# thermostats for high desert climate

Tags: thermostat

We live in Spokane, WA, a high-desert climate.  We don't need a programmable thermostat, but we do need one to keep an constant ambient temperature range. This may mean A/C during the day, and heat at night.  We have a heat pump.  What feature on a thermostat would allow us to automatically switch between heating and cooling?

Comment: I live in a similar climate (Pasco) and I like programable thermostat. If you don't mind having to program it we turn down the A/C to save power when no one is home during the day and also keep it a little cooler at night. However, during the winter the heat pump tends to work better when we keep a constant temperature.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want is referred to 'Auto Changeover".  But this feature is usually only on the higher end programmable thermostats now.

Comment: A quick search resulted in several in the ~$50 and under range with auto changeover. [The cheapest I found was $35.](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Honeywell-Deluxe-Digital-Non-Programmable-Thermostat-RTH5100B/203186916?N=5yc1vZc4ltZ1z0r6sh) I'd hardly call that high end, since the Nest brand can run $250.

Comment: I'm thinking what is available in stores.  Should have considered options online.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually need heat at night and AC during the day, that means that your house's level of insulation is so poor that it's really worth adding some.